# Jquery UI 1.10 - Getting the index of a tab inside an accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have a JQuery UI accordion, with some tabs inside each fold. I am trying to get the index of the tab that is currently open, in the accordion fold that is open. I had a solution that worked in a previous version of JQuery:

```
var active_tab = $(".accordion.ui-accordion-content-active.tabs").find("div:not(.ui-tabs-hide)").index()-1;
```

But, since I updated my JQuery version, I have not been able to get this to work, it always gives me a "-2".

I have also tried something like this:

```
var curTab = $('.accordion .ui-accordion-content-active .ui-tabs-active');
active_tab = curTab.index();
```

But this again just gives me a -1, regardless of the selected tab.

There is a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NALMd/) that showcases this behaviour.

To be clear, I need to be able to remember the state of the page, between refreshes.  So, I need the active accordion index, and the active tab index, which are then put in a cookie and checked on the refresh. The appropriate accordion and tab are then opened, and the page looks the same as it did before the refresh. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the proper functions (the `active` option) that jQuery UI gives you for finding the active accordion and tab:

```
var activeAccordionIndex = $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active");

var activeTabIndex = $(".accordion > div:eq(" + accordionIndex + ")").find(".tabs").tabs( "option", "active");
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/NALMd/6/)

Comment: This works really well, and actually gives me the exact selector I need to do some other things to the visible tab set.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery Tab's `.activate()` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate):

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true
});

$( ".tabs" ).tabs({
 activate: function( event, ui ) {
     active_tab = ui.newTab.index();
 }
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/NALMd/4/

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works well. However, I would like to avoid using a global variable, just because of how my scripts are organized.  Thanks for the info though, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Based on jsFiddle code you've presented, you must change it like this:

```
var curTab = $('.accordion h3.ui-state-active');
active_tab = curTab.index('h3');
```

First of all we select the active tab, then we get the correct index for it